# Does it matter if a RF television cable runs in the same duct as my internet Cat5e UTP cable?

Tags: internet-connection, cable, ping, cat5e

At my home I have a UTP cat5e cable with at least 50 meters that comes from the switch on my dad's office that occupies the same duct as the coaxial RF cable to my television when both arrives at my room's wall(from the roof). At least 3 meters of the cat5e cable works together with the coaxial RF cable. It is working well for the last 3 years, but now the internet is a little problematic at my room(just on my room, my dad's PC is fine). Somethimes it becomes really slow... doesn't fail completely, I can ping any internet address but there is at least 20% package loss. I already heard that it was not good to use both cables on the same duct but I have not given importance(I don't have another duct arriving on my bedroom).

So, now I'm wondering if something happends on the link or if is something "naturally" related to the television cable on the same duct.... Does someone had the same problem before? Do I need to install a STP or FTP cat5e cable?

Comment: coaxial and cat5e are often packaged together in mult-iuse cables, there should be no interference between the two. How are you testing for packet loss? What address are you testing to? Has anything changed on your network recently? do you get packet loss on any other computers?

Comment: Just using cmd.exe and ping -t google.com and watching the results.... There was no change recently unless the packet loss(it didn't happend before).... just on my computer...

Comment: Try using winmtr to test to both google.com and to your primary dns server. Let them run for a few hours and see which hop the packet loss shows on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both are standard cables, there should be no interference. Electrical cables could be a different story.  STP is usually not required.

Are there any severe bends in the CAT5e?  This can impact the cable negatively.  Any severe bends around sharp corners? Any chance cable was stretched when pulling through the duct.  That has a negative impact.

Was the cable a factory made and tested cable or one that was terminated on site?  If on site, check termination again.  Ideally, get a  cable tester and check the cable.

Also check the speed duplex on the switch/router and your Network card. A mismatch can cause packet loss. Unlikely if nothing has changed but worth checking.

Have you done a trace route to see if the loss is outside your control.  An issue a hop or two out could be the problem and that would likely be your ISP.